# sum a specyfic meta_value from custom post fields

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying  sum a specyfic meta_value funding. In my meta_value cell there are to custom post fields. One is funding and the other is ownContribution.

I have tried the example from codex page, but its not working, because when I echo the `$sumFunding` variable I get a 0.

```
  $meta_key = 'investments_details';
  $sumFunding = $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare(
  "
    SELECT sum(meta_value)
    FROM $wpdb->postmeta
    WHERE meta_key = %s", $meta_key) );
```

how to get this working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you have given doesn't contain meta fields you wrote.

Try this code:

```
$meta_key_1 = 'funding';
$meta_key_2='ownContribution';
$sumFunding = $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare(
"SELECT sum(meta_value)
 FROM $wpdb->postmeta
 WHERE meta_key = %s or meta_key = %s", $meta_key_1,$meta_key_2) );
```

If you want to it by the given post,

```
$meta_key_1 = 'funding';
$meta_key_2='ownContribution';
$post_id=SOME_ID_HERE;
$sumFunding = $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare(
"SELECT sum(meta_value)
 FROM $wpdb->postmeta
 WHERE post_id=%d and (meta_key = %s or meta_key = %s)",$post_id, $meta_key_1,$meta_key_2) );
```

UPDATE:
As you data values are in serialized data, it needs different approach:

```
 $post_id=SOME_ID_HERE;
 $investments_details=get_post_meta($post_id,'investments_details',true);
 $investments_details_sum=$investments_details['funding']+$investments_details['ownContribution'];
```

UPDATE2:
Loop all posts

```
$investments_details_sum=array();
$results = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT meta_key, meta_value, post_id FROM $wpdb->postmeta WHERE meta_key like 'investments_details'");
foreach($results as $result){
 $investments_details=unserialize($result->meta_value);
$investments_details_sum[$result->post_id] = $investments_details['funding'] + $investments_details['ownContribution'];
}
var_dump($investments_details_sum);
```

Comment: Almost there. How to add up the value od founding? Because now it's showing 3 (I understand it's because I have 3 post with founding custom fields) and what I  should get is 654.332,13 as a result of adding the values of founding?

Comment: Sorry i don't get what you mean. What is "654.332,13" ? Is it number? How did you get it?

Comment: in post_id 188 i have funding value 109375,00. In post_id 190 i have funding value 510779,50. In post_id 192 i have funding value 3417763,16. Heres a database screenshot https://pasteboard.co/HpwHlN9.jpg

Comment: no, their values are in php serialized format, so you can't sum them in single mysql query. My given codes are for the cases where the values are numbers. i am adding an update for your case now. check my answer above in 2 minutes

Comment: Ok, your update is working for one post. I need to select all post from database with the `investments_details` meta_key and add up all fundings. I could use for it   `$result = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT meta_key, meta_value FROM {$wpdb->prefix}postmeta WHERE meta_key like 'investments_details'");` but I don't know how to get the $investments_details['funding'] and add them up.

Comment: check my UPDATE2

Comment: Works. Thank you :)